# Cakephp checkbox css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, cakephp

I'm trying to put this on my cakephp project

http://jsfiddle.net/UVFD7/

however the output is this
[image]

instead of the one that shows in jsfiddle, how can I fix this?

the onoffswitch.css is in webroot

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 61px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    float: left; width: 50%; height: 33px; padding: 0; line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: " ";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #4EDE4C; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: " ";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    width: 31px; margin: 1px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 24px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

any help is appreciated, been breaking my head for a whole day, complete code is in jsfiddle

Comment: This seems like a DOM issue. Can you check to make sure the HTML is being outputted correctly?

Comment: By DOM issue, do you mean browser compatibility? I've checked the html and it outputs the checkbox if i remove the css

Comment: by DOM issue, I mean to check and make sure all of the elements, tags, and attributes in your document are the same as within the jsfiddle.

Comment: Try removing any other stylesheets from the layout. You probably have conflicting CSS.

Comment: What is your CakePHP code to output this kind of checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. in case if you see it doesn't work the other css might overwrite this css.

Also check if there tickbox css in imported css

```
echo $this->Html->tag('div', (
        $this->Form->checkbox('onoffswitch', array('hiddenField' => false, 'id'=>'myonoffswitch', 'class'=>'onoffswitch-checkbox', "checked")).
        $this->Form->label('tick',(
                                     $this->Html->tag('div','',array('class'=>'onoffswitch-inner')).
                                     $this->Html->tag('div','',array('class'=>'onoffswitch-switch'))
                                ), 
                                array('class'=>"onoffswitch-label", 'for'=>"myonoffswitch"))        
), array('class'=>'onoffswitch'));
```